# Azure REST API Get Branches returning 0 branches

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to get all branches for a project with

```
https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/tfvc/branches?&api- 
version=5.0
```

I use the credentials, organization, and project variables in other queries that are working. The request format is based off the example here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/branches/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

The response I am getting is

```
count value
----- -----
    0 {}
```

when there are many branches in the repository.

Should I be specifying the repository somewhere? Or what else? Thanks!

Comment: Is it a TFVC repository, or a Git repository? You're using the API for TFVC.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First you need to confirm which type of repository you need to use rest API to get branch from, git or tfvc.

If you want to get branches from a **tfvc** repo, then use the rest api as you refer to in your case.

But, you need to be aware that if the count you want to return is not 0, you should ensure that there are branches in your tfvc repo, not just folders and files.

To convert the folder in tfvc repo to branch, you can convert it in vs source control explorer. For details, please refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branch-folders-files?view=azure-devops).

[image]

If you want to get branches from a **git** repo, you need to use the [rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) as follows.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?api-version=5.0
```

[image]

Comment: I had a bit of confusion and it was a git repo, not tfvc. Got it working now through the git repo api you provided. Thank you very much.